# jQuery load() with callback function wont capture click()

Tags: jquery-load

I am having no luck in getting a jqueryui dialog to ajax load a form, which inturn submits via ajax.

Everything works upto the point of catching the form that is being submited and instead sending it through an ajax call. Thus the form action is triggered and the browser redirected. The ajax call is never made.

My code is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.viewOrder').click(function() {
    $('#displayOrder').load(this.href, [], function() {
        console.log("landed here");

            $('#blah').click(function() {
                console.log("submiting the form via ajax");

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/ajax/orderupdate",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,

                    //success
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("worked:");
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

.viewOrder is the a href that is ajax loaded. This works fine.
I have read many similar questions on here and it seems load() does not execute scripts that are embeded in the return html, but my return code is pure html no scripts. Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried seperating the callback funtion in the code into its own $(document).ready( { .... }); block but the same results. The form still submits as normal

Comment: The console.log("submiting the form via ajax"); line is appearing in firebug but the console.log("worked:"); isnt being printed to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events are bound on page load. At page load the form you are binding the click event does not exist. I use the livequery plugin but they added Live to jquery 4 which you can also use(i had some issues with IE so i went back to livequery)

So load livequery with your scripts http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

and change

$('#orderUpdate').submit(function() {

to

$("#orderUpdate").livequery("submit", function() {

Comment: changing $('#blah').click(function() to  $('#orderUpdate').live("submit", function() { part works. I get the console output but the ajax request isnt fired off and the form still submits i.e. the return false isnt working. If I remove all the code but the console output and the return false then that works.....insert another argh. Thanks tho

Comment: My bad. Faulty data: data, array option in the $.ajax function was causing the issue. Using live() fixed the problems.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should try and capture the [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) instead of the click, that way you prevent submits done by keyboard aswell, and it might even fix your problem.

Comment: Updated the code so that $('#blah').click(function() is now  $('#orderUpdate').submit(function() where #orderUpdate is the form id and same result..argh lol